# How to search to check if values of a column exist in another table as sub-string in BQ

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

I am familiar with the `CONTAINS_SUBSTR` function in BigQuery.  Here’s an example from the official BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#contains_substr) of how it works  (with minor modification):

```
WITH Recipes AS
 (SELECT 'Blueberry pancakes' as Breakfast, 'Egg salad sandwich' as Lunch, 'Potato dumplings' as Dinner UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Potato pancakes', 'Toasted cheese sandwich', 'Beef stroganoff' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ham scramble', 'Steak avocado salad', 'Tomato pasta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Avocado toast', 'Tomato soup', 'Blueberry salmon' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Corned beef hash', 'Lentil potato soup', 'Glazed ham')
SELECT * FROM Recipes;
```

**Recipes:**

| Breakfast | Lunch | Dinner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blueberry pancakes | Egg salad sandwich | Potato dumplings |
| Potato pancakes | Toasted cheese sandwich | Beef stroganoff |
| Ham scramble | Steak avocado salad | Tomato pasta |
| Avocado toast | Tomato soup | Blueberry salmon |
| Corned beef hash | Lentil potato soup | Glazed ham |

```
SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE CONTAINS_SUBSTR((Lunch), 'potato');
```

**Result:**

| Breakfast | Lunch | Dinner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Corned beef hash | Lentil potato soup | Glazed ham |

However, instead of a single STRING literal (`potato` in the above example), I want to be able to use a table with a single column that contains the keywords that I’m looking for:

```
WITH Keywords AS
(SELECT 'potato' as Ingredient UNION ALL
 SELECT 'cheese' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'egg')
```

**Keywords:**

| Ingredient |
| --- |
| potato |
| cheese |
| egg |

**Desired output:**

| Breakfast | Lunch | Dinner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Corned beef hash | Lentil potato soup | Glazed ham |
| Potato pancakes | Toasted cheese sandwich | Beef stroganoff |
| Blueberry pancakes | Egg salad sandwich | Potato dumplings |

Is there a way to use `CONTAINS_SUBSTR` or any other function and pass the `ingredient` column of `Keywords` as input to it to get the desired output?

Example of a query that I’m looking for (this does not work):

```
SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE CONTAINS_SUBSTR((Lunch), (SELECT Ingredient from Keywords));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (if you really want to use `CONTAINS_SUBSTR`)

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
SELECT  '''
  SELECT * FROM Recipes
  WHERE ''' || STRING_AGG('CONTAINS_SUBSTR(Lunch, "' || ingredient || '")', ' OR ') 
FROM Keywords
)
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Meantime, consider below that is using `REGEXP_CONTAINS` instead

```
SELECT r.* FROM Recipes r
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(Lunch, (SELECT '(?i)' || STRING_AGG(ingredient, '|') FROM Keywords))
```

which actually almost exactly what you wanted in `Example of a query that I’m looking for` ... :o)